# Unity instantiated object always references to same object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have code below to instantiate a UI element and move it:

```
void PopDialogBox()
{
 Vector3 pos = new Vector3(-horzExtent + .5f, -vertExtent, 0f);
 GameObject box = Instantiate(dialogBoxPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity, canvas.transform);

 box.name = "Box_" + Time.time;
 liveBoxes.Add(box);

 for (int i = 0; i < liveBoxes.Count; ++i)
 {
  Debug.Log("Move " + liveBoxes[i].name);
  StartCoroutine(SmoothMoveDialogBox(liveBoxes[i]));
 }
}
```

But the `box` is always the first created GameObject - they are referencing to the same object. As I can see in log and inspect using breakpoint:

[image]

But actually I have 2 or more instantiated objects! Since `Box_1.005764` and `Box_2.025746` both exist, while in log I can only see `Box_1.005764` being referenced.

The boxes were created per second and named accordingly to the time.

I'm confused because I'm using the object *after* instantiation so it should not be the prefab/previous ones, why this still happens?

---

As comments questioned, I replaced the for loop as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < liveBoxes.Count; ++i)
{
  Debug.Log("Move " + liveBoxes[i].name + ", all: " + liveBoxes.Count);
  StartCoroutine(SmoothMoveDialogBox(liveBoxes[i]));
}
```

It clears show that I have more than one boxes but they were not moving. But, I found if I **resize the game window** they occasionally move, and stop moving at certain point.

[image]

---

For @derHugo, the movement coroutine moves the target box:

```
IEnumerator SmoothMoveDialogBox(GameObject box)
{
  Vector3 pos = box.transform.position;
  Vector3 end = pos;
  end.y += boxMoveDistance;

  Debug.Log(box.name + " from " + pos + ", to " + end);

  while (Vector3.Distance(pos, end) > Mathf.Epsilon)
  {
    Vector3 target = Vector3.MoveTowards(pos, end, boxMoveSpeed);
    box.transform.position = target;
    pos = box.transform.position;
    yield return null;
  }
}
```

For any furthur check see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/KHN190/fc66045bbb5d18bd92ab3d08940a5eb2).

Comment: Problem is okay but judging the reason of this problem cannot be so easy until you don't paste any clue about creating Box_1, Box_2 kind of objects.

Comment: @hygull what should I provide in extra? The objects were created in the line `Instantiate`.

Comment: What are box_1 box_2, you are hiding the code

Comment: @ilansch pls see updated post.

Comment: You created only 1 instance box object, check the .count of liveboxes. Thats why you always target the same instance. Why would you think you have more instances?

Comment: @ilansch no they are not. I also checked `GetHashCode` they are not same. I updated my post also.

Comment: Could you post the code of `SmoothMoveDialogBox`?

Comment: @derHugo I updated the post but I'm afraid it'll be too long. I posted the complete code on gist, in fact, the script is fine. It's the Canvas setting breaking my code. https://gist.github.com/KHN190/fc66045bbb5d18bd92ab3d08940a5eb2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by canvas. But I still don't understand.

The default canvas should work, but I set the canvas render mode to "screenspace - camera" and attached main camera to it (also "worldspace" doesn't work).

I changed back to the default "screenspace - overlay" and now it works.